# Premature end of char class in interpolated regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I can't seem to solve this issue, hope someone can help:

**Nilfacs** is an array of strings pulled from a hash.

For this line:

```
looping_finaltext = finaltext.reject {|sentence| nilfacs.any? {|fac| sentence =~ /#{(fac)}/i}}
```

I get the following errors: `warning: character class has ']' without escape: /[[]]/`
and
`block (2 levels) in <main>': premature end of char-class: /[[]]/i (RegexpError)`

All of the strings are just normal words (like "condition") and do not contain characters that should need to be escaped.

Is this an indication that something unanticipated is being fed into the array as a string? Or is there something wrong with my syntax in this line?

Comment: Are you expecting `fac` to contain actual Regexp content, ie. if `fac` is `.*` then anything is matched, or should it directly match a string like this: `".*"`?

Comment: No need to put `fac` in parens, btw. Without knowing a bit more context it may be difficult to help.

Comment: What does it look like if you do `p fac` or `p nilfacs`? That's the key to your problem.

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks for the tip! I'm new at this, didn't know about using "p". The loop I'm using to modify the array of strings is adding empty arrays ("[[]]]" appears at the end). Now that I know the problem, I can look at what's been suggested below and figure out how to fix it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Is this an indication that something unanticipated is being fed into the array as a string?*

Yes, that is it exactly. I expect that you have nested arrays and somewhere in there you have an array of an empty array `[[]]` whose to_s representation produces the result you found.

When you use interpolation in a regex literal the characters in your source are treated as they would be in regex. Just as `/b[/` is not a valid regular expression, so `foo="b["; bar=/#{foo}/` is not valid.

```
nilfacs = [ "a[]", "b[", "c]", [[]] ]

nilfacs.each do |fac|
  begin
    p /#{fac}/
  rescue RegexpError=>e
    puts e
  end
end

#=> empty char-class: /a[]/
#=> premature end of char-class: /b[/
#=> /c]/
#=> warning: regular expression has ']' without escape: /[[]]/
#=> premature end of char-class: /[[]]/
```

If you want to use your strings as literal characters, you want to use [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
nilfacs.each do |fac|
  p /#{Regexp.escape fac}/
end
#=> /a\[\]/
#=> /b\[/
#=> /c\]/
```

Alternatively, you may want to use `Regexp.union` to create a single regexp from your array that matches all the literal strings therein:

```
rejects = %w[dog cat]
re = Regexp.new(Regexp.union(rejects).source,'i') #=> /dog|cat/i
looping_finaltext = finaltext.reject{ |sentence| sentence=~re }
```

Comment: You need to do a bit messing around to get an "ignore case" modifier on the regex when using `Regexp.union`, I haven't found a better way than this `Regexp.new(Regexp.union(a).source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)` mess.

Comment: @mu Me either; I didn't notice that the OP had a `/i` on there. Good call. Note that you can use `"i"` in lieu of `Regexp::IGNORECASE`.

Comment: Re: `"i"`: I'm already beating it with the ugly stick, might as go all the way and use `Regexp::IGNORECASE` :)

Answer (score 2):

> **Nilfacs** is an array of strings pulled from a hash.

Probably not, `nilfacs` almost certainly has an empty AoA as a member. Try this in `irb` and you'll see:

```
>> a = [[]]
>> /#{a}/
(irb):4: warning: character class has ']' without escape: /[[]]/
RegexpError: premature end of char-class: /[[]]/
```

Either that or you have the string `'[[]]'` in `nilfacs`:

```
>> a = '[[]]'
>> /#{a}/
(irb):6: warning: character class has ']' without escape: /[[]]/
RegexpError: premature end of char-class: /[[]]/
```

Once you fix your `nilfacs` to be a the array of strings that you want it to be, you can clean up your code by using a single regex instead of `any?`:

```
re = Regexp.new(Regexp.union(nilfacs).source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
looping_finaltext = finaltext.reject { |sentence| sentence =~ re }
```

The regex engine can check all the patterns at once to avoid the overhead of invoking the `String#=~` over and over again inside the `any?` block.